# fontawesome integration in <ion-icon> Ionic 4 - Angular 7

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, font-awesome, ionic4

I m trying to integrate fontawesome in my ionic4 app.

I have followed this tutorial 
https://yannbraga.com/2017/06/28/how-to-use-custom-icons-on-ionic-3/

with some modifications for ionic4.

Now I can display the fontawesome using

```
<i class="fas fa-alicorn"></i>
```

or

```
<ion-icon class="fas fa-alicorn"></ion-icon>
```

But I would like to use like this (like a normal ion-icon)

```
<ion-icon name="fas fa-alicorn"></ion-icon>
```

When i try this i ve got an error : "aarlbodj.entry.js:1 icon was not resolved" . Anyone in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

`ion-icon` component resolves the `name` attribute from [ion-icons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/).You are giving some class names as name attribute in `ion-icon` component.

If you want to use fontawesome icons in an Ionic 4 app, Install this [package](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome).

Answer (score 0):

angular-fontawesome is an official angular component for Font Awesome5 and it's easily integrated with Ionic4 projects. Go through the instructions on following link. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324301.